# How to crosscompile a hello world C program for ARM

Tags: c, gcc, arm, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I have this simple program with its sources in a 'src' folder and the includes in the 'inc' folder. Normally i compile this with:

```
gcc -I../inc *.c
```

This leaves 'a.out' as program which works fine on that pc.

But how do i compile this for my BeagleBone Black (ARM)? With this i am thinking about:

```
gcc (some arguments to crosscompile for arm) -I../inc *.c
```

Comment: Have you installed an ARM toolchain on your PC ?

Comment: you don't `compile` it, actually you [cross-compile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#GCC_and_cross_compilation) it.

Comment: Thank you for your question Paul. Yes i have. I am using the git archive and uboot for the kernel, so i am already using "make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- ARCH=arm uImage".

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Good question Dipto, the point is that i am not actually shure how to cross-comile it for ARM and doing nothing does not give errors. I have tried "gcc CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- ARCH=arm -I../inc *.c" which results in: "gcc: error: CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-: No such file or directory" and "gcc: error: ARCH=arm: No such file or directory".

Comment: You're getting confused between makefile options and gcc options - create a simple makefile for your project in the same style as your existing ARM makefile and then use `make CROSS_COMPILE=...` as you normally would. Alternatively look at the build commands generated when you make uImage and use the gcc switches from that.

Comment: Sorry your right, bad mistake. But my kernel makefile is 1500 lines long. I don't intent diving into that. Are there no arguments i can give to gcc to make it crosscompile for arm?

Comment: Well, for a beaglebone black, you should be using an arm-linux-gnueabihf- toolchain.

Comment: Don't be frightened to "dive in" - that is the best way to learn!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you say you can use `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- ARCH=arm uImage` you should have arm gnueabi toolchain available at your disposal. It should be then as easy as calling it like

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I../inc *.c
```

Comment: Auselen, you are one awesome sir. This is exactly what i was looking for. And it works!